# Load website through IP and change HTTP header Host in Android Java

Tags: java, android, browser, dns, ip

I'd like to write an application in Java which would be just browser. But I need it to show some webpage with different domain name.
Fxp. IP: 10.0.0.2 with domain name "mydomain". It should work just like this line in hosts file:

```
10.0.0.2 mydomain
```

Is this possible without changing local hosts file or creating local DNS server?

I'd like to use this browser on Android phone.

Edit:
I'm currently using Webview for load website like this:

```
    String url = "http://10.0.0.2";
    WebView view = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoad", url);
            if ((url.startsWith("http://mydomain")) || (url.startsWith("http://10.0.0.2"))) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d("onPageStarted", url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("onLoadResource", url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("onPageFinished", url);
        }
    });

    Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    extraHeaders.put("Host","mydomain");

    view.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
```

It's working, but there is a problem with resources. I need every request to load with "Host" header modified and through IP as url. Can I edit this in onLoadResource event or where and how should I do that?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: What are you using for the browser part? *Of course* it's possible in principle for a browser to display resources from arbitrary sources upon entering any given URL. But without knowing what limitations you've got....

Comment: I'm currently using Webview I'll update my question.